# Which Pantone guide do I require?

Tags: color, pantone

I have a sports item which has some wear & tear. I want to identify the color using a Pantone guide, to order an ink and restore the item.

The sports item has a glossy surface, so I think I want "Coated"?

I don't know if I need the Pantone Color Bridge Guide or the Formula Guide. I've also seen "Solid", "CMYK" and "Plus" guides.

Pantone recommended the Formula Guide but i'm worried an ink provider might want CMYK or RGB codes.

Could someone please help explain which guide would be best?

And do Bridge and Formula contain the same number of colors?

Comment: Pantone chart may not be what your looking for since your looking into dying and not ink on paper.

Comment: Are you specifically going to be ordering a printing ink to do this matching? 200 bucks for a pantone book seems a very expensive way to go about a one-off colour-match. If you're really going to just try to match a colour on an unknown substrate by eye, I'd suggest you nip round to your local DIY superstore & check out their paint chip cards. Take a few outdoors to do the eyeballing. Send the best match to the supplier.

Comment: Pantone spot colour inks are not made using CMYK or RGB codes.  They are mixed using the formulas in the book. I was in the print industry for many years, and have mixed literally thousands of Pantone inks.  Also note that Pantone spot colour inks are semi-transparent, and may not work on already coloured fabrics. They are designed to be printed on a white substrate.  Also inks for coated stock are generally not glossy themselves. Any gloss or shine comes from either the substrate, or an additional gloss coating on top. You may need to rethink this project. I doubt it will work TBH.

Comment: @BillyKerr The item is a synthetic-leather soccer ball, with a glossy white surface. The ball has coloured marks but some specs have come away, leaving white underneath. I was hoping to color-match, request a permanent ink pen and then to fill the small specs of white. However, if you have more knowledge of this could I please request your advice?

Comment: @Tetsujin To be honest price isn't a problem. The sports item is very rare and memorabilia from an actual event. What is the "solid" in some color guides? And may I ask, the item is synthetic leather with a glossy surface. What sort of ink would I need? I was hoping to use a pen to manually fill in the missing specs of color.

Comment: @joojaa I'm not sure about dying. Originally the soccer ball was printed in Pakistan. I'd like to manually restore the color (it's just a few small specs a few millimetres across) and i assumed I would get a custom permanent ink and use a pen but i don't know much about pen inks.

Comment: If you have something of actually significant monetary value, you risk dramatically reducing its worth by attempting DIY repairs. Don't do it. It will be worth more in its current condition. Consult an expert in the field, don't risk ruining it with DIY. Guide prices form a different genre. 1964 fair condition, sonic blue Fender Strat £15,000 UKP. 1964 Strat, refinished to 'as new' condition, 2,500.. Ruined.

Comment: @Tetsujin The monetary value doesn't matter because i don't have any intention of selling it. Do you know what sorts of inks I would need for synthetic leather, or how I could find out?

Comment: Someone will think of it eventually, even if it's your grandkids in 60 years. Take it to an expert in the field, don't rely on guesses from people who cannot get hands-on.

Comment: @Tetsujin I see we're both located in the same area (I'm about 30 miles away). Do you know who would be an expert in our region of the world? What sort of expert would I be after? I think restoring ink on a synthetic-leather soccer ball would be a little too specific?

Comment: Your guess is as good as mine, sorry.

Comment: To be honest with you, I strongly suspect that ink will not work on leather and you will risk ruining it. Maybe find a professional leather restorer. If they can't do it themselves, they may know someone who can.

Comment: I'm thinking some kind of advanced latex-substitute/acrylic, screen-print stuff. So far outside my area of expertise I wouldn't like to make any real prediction. I'm still going to say you will ruin the value, both intrinsic and extrinsic, if you restore it to 'as new' condition. To take a wild aside - what if you had the ball Pele scored a winning penalty with & you replaced his boot-scuff with fresh ink?

Comment: @Tetsujin apparently [leather acrylic paints](https://www.amazon.co.uk/acrylic-paint-leather/s?k=acrylic+paint+for+leather) are actually a thing. Who knew!

Comment: @Tetsujin Also found this UK site: https://www.leatherpaint.co.uk/ - they have an email address and so perhaps the OP could ask for their advice. This is outside my experience too. Also there's an [Arts & Crafts Stack Exchange](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/) which might be able to shine some more light on the problem.